# Querying LDAP multi-value attributes using Openquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express to query an LDAP linked server like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM OPENQUERY
(MYLINKEDSERVER, 
'SELECT  *
FROM ''LDAP://myserver:389/o=root''
        where telephonenumber = ''9*''
        AND categoryid = ''3''   ')
```

I manage to get the query working when I'm just using `SELECT *`, but I'm having problems with selection the `categoryid` field, as it's a multi-valued parameter.

I get the error:

> Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject"
>   for linked server "MyLinkedServer". Could not convert the data value
>   due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow

As I have seen in other ADSI tutorials, it's not possible to query multi-valued parameters as they don't fit in a relational database, but my problem is that this attribute is not really multi-valued (only by definition), as it always stores a single value.

Is there any way to get the first-value of a multi-valued attribute?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I seem to recall that attributes in X.500 are case sensitive. Try querying categoryId and telephoneNumber (with capital I and N respectively). Just a guess, though. :)

Comment: As for multivalued, when in the WHERE clause, you can just stack them with ANDs, like `WHERE memberOf='onegroup' AND memberOf='anotherGroup'`. Note sure if that works with "regular" attributes, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I would discard the syntax as the root of the problem. I'm getting the following error message: Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "MyLinkedServer". Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow.      Normally this message is linked to selecting a multi-valued attribute. So I can filter by any of these multi-valued attribute but I cannot select them.

Comment: If I remember correctly, as soon as an LDAP attribute is *defined* to be multi-valued (no matter whether it really contains multiple values or not), it **cannot** be read by the ADO.NET provider. This provider is deprecated anyway, so I wouldn't spend too much time on working with a "dead horse"....

Comment: I didn't know it was deprecated, I still can find it with SQL Express 2012... So that means that there is a newer version of this provider?